# mysql load and query showing wrong results

Tags: mysql, file-io, load

I am using mysql server version 5.1.73.
I am loading this file: http://delphi.cs.csubak.edu/~wroyer/TGradebook/final/majors.data
I am loading my data with

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'majors.data'
>   REPLACE
>   INTO TABLE Majors
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '| ';

When I run the query `SELECT * FROM Majors;` I get the following output:

```
+------+--------------------------------+-------------+  
| Code | Major                          | shortName   |  
+------+--------------------------------+-------------+  
 |  -1 | Undeclared                     | Undeclared  
   | 1 | Computer Science               | Comp Sci  
       | Mathematics                    | Math  
    |3 | Pre-Engineering                | Pre-Eng  
    |4 | Physics                        | Physics  
    |5 | Geology                        | Geology  
   | 6 | Anthropology                   | Anthropo  
    |7 | Biology                        | Biology  
  |  8 | Chemistry                      | Chemistry  
 |   9 | Natural Sciences               | Natura Sci  
    |0 | Nursing                        | Nursing  
        |Art                            | Art  
    |2 | Communications                 | Communi  
    |3 | English                        | English  
     | | History                        | Histry  
 |  35 | Modern Languages               | Modern Lan  
      || Music                          | Music  
 |  37 | Philosophy                     | Philosophy  
    |8 | Theatre                        | Theatre  
 |  39 | Religious Studies              | Reglig Stu  
 |  40 | Literatures                    | Literature  
 |  50 | Accounting                     | Accounting  
 |  51 | Business Administration        | Busini Adm  
  | 52 | Economics                      | Economics  
 |  53 | Environmental Resource Mgmt.   | EnvRes Mmt  
 |  54 | Management & Marketing         | Mgmt & Mkt  
        |Management Information Systems | MIS  
 |  56 | Public Policy Administration   | Pub Po Adm  
    |7 | Finance                        | Finance  
 |  70 | Advanced Educational Studies   | Adv Edu St  
 |  71 | Criminal Justice               | Crimin Stu  
 |  72 | Liberal Studies                | Liberal St  
 |  73 | Physical Education             | Physicl Ed  
 |  74 | Political Science              | Politi Sci  
 |  75 | Psychology                     | Psychology  
 |  76 | Social Work                    | Social Wrk  
  | 77 | Sociology                      | Sociology  
 |  78 | Special Education              | Special Ed  
 |  79 | Teacher Education              | Teacher Ed  
 |  80 | Kinesiology                    | Kinesiolog  
 |  90 | Seeking Credential             | Seek Crede  
|   91 | Special Major                  | Special Mj  |  
+------+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

If I run `SELECT * FROM Majors WHERE Code = 2;` I get:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+
| Code | Major       | shortName |
+------+-------------+-----------+
     | | Mathematics | Math
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Is this just a mysql formatting issue?

Comment: Please post your tables description, p.e. data types and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add LINES TERMINATED with the suitable value depending on Windows vs Unix.

Comment: This was the issue.  
After seeing your comment and doing a little more research I was able to fix the problem by adding `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`